# Correct term for a “distraction car”

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I’m looking for the term used to indicate a car when it is used to “distract” possible ill-intentioned people from committing a crime.

For instance  when a President (or an important politician)  moves by car from a place to another, the security service use one or more cars similar to the one used by the President so that in case of a terrorist attack, for example, the terrorists don’t  actually know which is the target car.

Is there a term for the car/s used to “distract”  and confuse  possible assaulters?

Answer (score 11):

In general they could be referred to as ***"decoys".***

**decoy**

> something or someone used to trick or confuse people, especially something or someone that is not what they appear to be:

On the other hand, in your specific example, the Secret Service refers to them as ***spares***.

> "The 'Stagecoach,' the name for whatever car the President is in, is the whole focus of Presidential Motorcade. Everything is centered on making sure that car makes it to its destination. In addition to 'Stagecoach,' at least one identical car always accompanies it, and sometimes many more. These cars, known as **'Spares,'** are used as a backup and blocking vehicle should POTUS's vehicle have a mechanical issue or is attacked, ***as well as serving as decoys.***

[The Warzone](https://www.thedrive.com/the-war-zone/4518/the-fascinating-anatomy-of-the-presidential-motorcade)

This information is also included on [Endurance](https://www.endurancewarranty.com/learning-center/tech/how-the-presidential-motorcade-works/)

> ...whatever car the President is driving in, the **codename “spares”** refers to the identical vehicles accompanying the one carrying the President. Sometimes those cars are used as a backup in case of breakdown or accident. ***Other times they are used as security decoys.***

I have also heard the word "dummy" used. As mentioned by Edwin Ashworth  (and Thanks!) below, they could be referred to as a "decoy".

Comment: Please show that 'decoy' is an answer.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - I think decoy is probably more appropriate, “spares” appears to refer to cars as a backup support.

Comment: And of course you can use "decoy car" if you need specifically to say it is a car (rather than a bus, van, plane, etc).